# Why can't the ??-operator be applied to generic types, but a null-check can be applied?

Tags: c#

If I have a generic function that returns a `T` or some default value I want to use the `??` operator

```
T f<T>(T a, T b)
{
    return a ?? b;
}
```

This fails with the message

> Operator '??' cannot  be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'

I assume this is because `T` might not be nullable. But I would also assume that the `??` operator above should do the same as

```
T f<T>(T a, T b)
{
    var a_ = a;
    return a_ != null ? a_ : b;
}
```

And the second code compiles without a problem.

So why are those cases handled differently even though they should do the same?

Comment: Is your second argument, `b`, intended to be the default value of `T`?

Comment: How does it *know* that `T` is of reference type ? If it doesn't know how does it compare potential `struct` with `null`

Comment: @Fabjan it doesn't. The `_a != null` is removed by the JIT if `T` ends up being a reference type (in fact it compiles to `box; brtrue`, which is a always `true` if `T` is a reference type, but the JIT recognises this)

Comment: It shouldn't compile in the first place (because of type safety).

Comment: @Fabjan It does compile, and it safely compiles. See my dotnetfiddle link above.

Comment: @Fabjan I don't follow - `(null)a` is *never* legal, it's not valid C#

Comment: What I am saying is that imo it is illogical that with type conversions it doesn't allow to convert `T` to `null` like `return null` or `T x = null` unless there is a generic type constraint there `where T : class` but when comparing the type `T` to `null` it allows to do it. But it is a question to C# team so nevermind.

Comment: It makes sense that `return null` or `T x = null` are not allowed if `T` is unconstrained. However `x == null` is a very useful test in generic methods: if you need it, it's unavoidable. Note that the compiler itself will sometimes emit `default(T) == null` to see whether `T` is a reference or value type (with different code paths for both), [e.g. here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQBMQGoA+ABATARgFgAobAZgAI8KBhAHgBUA+CgbxIs4oAcEBLAG4R4FBhQAeAbg5dyVfAAYKAWQAUASjYyusgOwSA/ADoGAewDKMfgDsA5hunEdAXxLOgA=)

Comment: @canton7 It makes even more sense if we think about `struct` (and all derived types) as a light-weight object and especially considering the fact that most of types in C# derive from `System.Object`. Maybe that's why it is allowed to compare a potential struct type value with `null`. I hope Eric Lippert will leave a comment on this one.

Comment: A quote from [Eric Lippert's post in his blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/08/06/not-everything-derives-from-object/): 'And since generic types and methods ultimately are only ever used at runtime when fully "constructed" with "concrete" type arguments, type parameter types are always convertible to object'. Maybe that is the explanation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197499/discussion-between-canton7-and-fabjan).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this question on dotnet/csharplang](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/505#issuecomment-297785135):

> The reason for this is that ?? is intended to unwrap the type on the left if the type on hte left is `Nullable<T>`. In other words, today i can write:
>
> ```
> int? x ...;
> int y ...;
> int z = x ?? y;
> ```
>
> So, it's not the case that "x ?? y" translates to "x != null ? x : y". It can translate to "x != null ? x.Value : y".
>
> Since we don't know if T is a value or reference type, we cannot effectively do the transformation. However, when T is constrained to "class" or "struct" (and in the latter case, is a T?), then we can do the transformation.

See the rest of that thread for a wider discussion.

There's a [discussion around relaxing this](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1720).

Answer (score 0):

Not every object is nullable...  Classes are nullable.  Therefore, you have to indicate that what you are passing in is a class.  Alternatively, use `default(T)` instead of `null`, but if you pass in 'int' for T, that will be zero instead of `null`.

```
T f<T>(T a, T b)
   where T: class
{
     ....
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What is T struct or class? Thats why it cant return default type.

```
T fa<T>(T a, T b)where T :class
{
return a ?? b;
}
```

Comment: I think the point made in the question is that the JIT could reduce `a ?? b` to just `a` if `T` is a value type, just as it reduces `a_ != null ? a_ : b` to just `a_` if T is a value type (i.e. `a_ != null` is always legal, it's just always `true` if `a` is a value type). The question is why isn't this allowed.

Comment: I think question is why it cant?  Answer was it can if you say T is ref .